# Which kinds of high level API of tensorflow should I learn?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have studied tensorflow for about one month. I just feel that creating a network with primitive operations of Tensorflow is very verbose. Then I found some high level API, such as TF-Slim, TF Learn, Keras. But multiple choices confuse me so that I don't know which I should learn.

TF-Slim is a lightweight library for defining, training and evaluating complex models in TensorFlow, but as I [investigated](https://www.quora.com/What-will-Keras-do-with-TensorFlow-Slim), it's only for convnets. What networks Keras can build are more diverse.

Can Anyone give a comparision between them so that I could choose which high level API I should learn ? In terms of :

```
1. popularity: which ones are the most popular ?
2. practicality: what kinds of network can they build ?
3. performance: what's their training/inference performance ?
... something else
```

Hope someone could give me a suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: If it could help..! https://medium.com/implodinggradients/tensorflow-or-keras-which-one-should-i-learn-5dd7fa3f9ca0

Comment: I only know keras. You can build lots of networks, fully connected, convolution (1d, 2d, 3d), recurrent (GRU and LSTM included), and you can mix all of them in the same model. You can create your model quite freely with branches, multiple inputs and multiple outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start with Keras.

It´s very easy to learn, it has a broad user base (see Shobhits link), there is a ton of reference code out there on GitHub and in tutorials / MOOCs / eBooks etc. and you can build almost anything with it. And I personally think that is has a good documentation (although some might disagree with that...).

Since it´s an API that connects to Tensorflow, Theano, CNTK (and possibly more frameworks in the future) you have even more flexibility.

Don´t worry too much about performance. That´s really not important while youre learning.